# Reading your site's content with PURGECSS Joomla Template

Tags: extensions, css

Is there a [PurgeCSS](https://purgecss.com/configuration.html#options) guide to setting up with a Joomla! Template. WP has [this guide](https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss/tree/master/packages). My problem  is I can't get it to read all the pages in the site.

**What should I put in `content: [],`?**

Now - I want it to read through my site's pages including level 3 subs:

- /work/example
- /blog/article1

Specifying '/work/' doesn't produce any results. It seems to only work with relative paths - but doesn't go deep enough: '../**/*.php'

**My Setup:**

1. The config.js file is set up in my /templates/dir/ folder.
2. ```
   module.exports = {
       content: ['../../../**/*.php','../../../../**/*.php','../js/*.js',],
       safelist: {
           standard: ['g1-bkg', 'is-visible', 'flex@xs', 'white'],
           deep: [/mega-nav/, /js/],
       },
       defaultExtractor: content => content.match(/[\w-/:%@]+(?<!:)/g) || []
   };
   ```
3. I'm using [prepros](https://prepros.io/help/custom-tools).